# How to zip a Universal Build Package in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, cicd

I have a pipeline set up to build a Universal Package. After it finishes, I get a build package (contains folders and required config files as per my solution). I want that to be packaged into a zip file.

[image]

**Try1:**

I have tried to create another inline-PowerShell step that will create a zip file and place it inside the build folder but it doesn't create any. It does create on my local, but not in the pipeline.

Then I have tried another option. I have added the following step to do the job. It creates the zip folder, but I don't see a zip file when I download it.

[image]

**Note:**
Is there a way to set up a publish profile so that it can automatically publish the build content into a zip folder?

Comment: what is "doesn't create any"? what is the inline code?

Comment: Yes, it was an inline PowerShell script. It works on my local folders, but not in the pipeline.

Comment: what is the code? what is the logs? anyway, you can use "Archive Files task": https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/archive-files?view=azure-devops

Comment: I am compressing the content of the folder using this code 

Compress-Archive -CompressionLevel Fastest -Path *.* -DestinationPath "$outputDir/$VSver`_$buildTime.zip"

Comment: Let me try the "Archive Files" task.

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't help out.

Comment: Can you share you zip task configuration and publish universal artifacts configuration?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233465/discussion-between-mukesh-kumar-and-shayki-abramczyk).

Answer (score 1):

Universal packages publish task should be the last task in your pipeline. You need to put Archive Files task before Universal packages publish task.

If you want to download the zip files on your local machine. You can aslo use [publish build artifacts task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/publish-build-artifacts?view=azure-devops) to publish the zip files as build artifacts. Then you can download the artifacts in the build summary UI page.

[image]